# Parsing dot separated keys to nested YAML objects with SnakeYaml

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I have the following `HashMap`

```
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("a.b", "c");
 map.put("a.d", "e");
```

And the following code to write the map to a YAML file with SnakeYAML

```
 DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
 options.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
 options.setPrettyFlow(true);
 Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
 String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "file.yaml";

 try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path)) {
   yaml.dump(map, fileWriter);
 } catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
```

After `cat file.yaml` I can see that the file contains the following

```
a.b: c
a.d: e
```

However, I'm looking to format the output so that the dot separated keys are in fact nested objects

```
a:
  b: c
  d: e
```

I have tried changing `options.setIdent()` and changing the `FlowStyle` to `FLOW`, but so far I've had no luck.

How can I do this in Java with `SnakeYAML`? Or do I have change my approach and use another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to configure `SnakeYAML` to split the keys because as far as it is concerned, `a.b` and `a.d` are valid keys, hence it is generating the YAML with those keys. If you have control over how the input map is formed, then the best thing to do would be to create a map with nested maps, with keys the way you expect in the final yaml. Something like the below:

```java
Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("b", "c");
innerMap.put("d", "e");
input.put("a", innerMap);
```

On the other hand, if you don't have control over how the input map is formed, then you can do some preprocessing, to split the input keys and form nested maps, before passing the map to SnakeYAML. The code might look something like the below:

```java
public static String toYamlNestedKeys(Map<String, Object> input) {
    prepareInput(input);

    DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
    dumperOptions.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(dumperOptions);
    String result = yaml.dump(input);

    LOGGER.info("Result: \n{}", result);
    return result;
}

private static void prepareInput(Map<String, Object> input) {
    List<String> keysToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();

    input.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (key.contains(".")) {
            keysToRemove.add(key);
            output.putAll(mergeValues(output, splitKey(key, value)));
        }
    });

    // Remove entries that have been converted into nested maps
    keysToRemove.forEach(key -> {
        input.remove(key);
    });

    // Add the nested maps
    output.forEach((key, value) -> {
        input.put(key, value);
    });
}

private static Map<String, Object> mergeValues(Map<String, Object> completeOutput, Map<String, Object> tempOutput) {
    Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = tempOutput.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get();
    Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();
    output.putAll(completeOutput);

    if (completeOutput.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
        output.put(entry.getKey(),
            mergeValues(
                    (Map<String, Object>) completeOutput.get(entry.getKey()),
                    (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue()
            )
        );
    } else {
        output.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return output;
}

private static Map<String, Object> splitKey(String key, Object value) {
    Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();

    int dotIndex = key.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex == -1 || dotIndex == key.length() - 1) {
        output.put(key, value);
    } else {
        String innerKey = key.substring(dotIndex + 1, key.length());
        Map<String, Object> innerObject = new HashMap<>();
        innerObject.put(innerKey, value);

        String outerKey = key.substring(0, dotIndex);
        output.putAll(splitKey(outerKey, innerObject));
    }

    return output;
}
```

Below is a unit test, written in Spock, that tests the above code:

```
void 'test to yaml nested keys'() {
    given:
    String expectedOutput = '''
    a:
      b: c
      d: e
      f:
        g: h
    i.: j
    k: l
    m:
      n: o
    p:
      q:
        r: s
    '''

    and:
    def input = [
            'a.b': 'c',
            'a.d': 'e',
            'a.f.g': 'h',
            'i.': 'j',
            'k': 'l',
            'm': ['n': 'o'],
            'p.q': ['r': 's'],
    ]

    when:
    String output = TestUtil.toYamlNestedKeys(input)

    then:
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml()
    yaml.load(output) == yaml.load(expectedOutput)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up creating a recursive solution to split the keys and create nested maps. From there, I just used SnakeYAML as normal and it works a treat.